# Make specific column editable/non editable in JTable

Tags: java, swing, date, checkbox, jtable

This is front end of the attendance sheet of the particular month and the month can be changed from `combobox` above the date there is one `checkbox`
The significance of that `checkbox` is that if it is selected all members attendance for that day is marked and if any of the `checkbox` of the member attendance is unchecked then select all `checkbox` that in the moment are unchecked.Now I want my date column should enable or editable according to current date.

[Here is the JTable I have created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9hdz.png)

I want the specific column of current date should be editable and other that current date should be non editable or disable or read only in jtable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the [`isCellEditable(row,col)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#isCellEditable-int-int-) method of the table and return `true` for any row of the column that matches the current date.